# Pytorch couldn't build multi scaled kernel nested model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to create a modified MNIST model which takes input 1x28x28 MNIST tensor images, and it kind of branches into different models with different sized kernels, and accumulates at the end, so as to give a multi-scale-kerneled response in the spatial domain of the images. I'm worried about the model, since, I'm unable to construct it.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data as Data
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
import timeit
import unittest


torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(0)

# check availability of GPU and set the device accordingly

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


# define a transforms for preparing the dataset
transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(), # convert the image to a pytorch tensor
        transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,)) # normalise the images with mean and std of the dataset
        ])

# Load the MNIST training, test datasets using `torchvision.datasets.MNIST` using the transform defined above

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./data',train=True,transform=transform,download=True)
test_dataset =  datasets.MNIST('./data',train=False,transform=transform,download=True)


# create dataloaders for training and test datasets
# use a batch size of 32 and set shuffle=True for the training set

train_dataloader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)


# My Net

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        # define a conv layer with output channels as 16, kernel size of 3 and stride of 1
        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, 1) # Input = 1x28x28  Output = 16x26x26
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 5, 1) # Input = 1x28x28  Output = 16x24x24
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 7, 1) # Input = 1x28x28  Output = 16x22x22

        # define a conv layer with output channels as 32, kernel size of 3 and stride of 1
        self.conv21 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, 1) # Input = 16x26x26 Output = 32x24x24
        self.conv22 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1) # Input = 16x24x24 Output = 32x20x20
        self.conv23 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 7, 1) # Input = 16x22x22 Output = 32x16x16

        # define a conv layer with output channels as 64, kernel size of 3 and stride of 1
        self.conv31 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1) # Input = 32x24x24 Output = 64x22x22
        self.conv32 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5, 1) # Input = 32x20x20 Output = 64x16x16
        self.conv33 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 7, 1) # Input = 32x16x16 Output = 64x10x10

        # define a max pooling layer with kernel size 2
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2), # Output = 64x11x11
        # define dropout layer with a probability of 0.25
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        # define dropout layer with a probability of 0.5
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        # define a linear(dense) layer with 128 output features
        self.fc11 = nn.Linear(64*11*11, 128)
        self.fc12 = nn.Linear(64*8*8, 128)      # after maxpooling 2x2
        self.fc13 = nn.Linear(64*5*5, 128)

        # define a linear(dense) layer with output features corresponding to the number of classes in the dataset
        self.fc21 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.fc22 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.fc23 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

        self.fc33 = nn.Linear(30,10)
        

    def forward(self, x1):
        # Use the layers defined above in a sequential way (folow the same as the layer definitions above) and 
        # write the forward pass, after each of conv1, conv2, conv3 and fc1 use a relu activation. 
        

        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x1))
        x = F.relu(self.conv21(x))
        x = F.relu(self.maxpool(self.conv31(x)))
        #x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = x.view(-1,64*11*11)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc11(x))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc21(x)

        y = F.relu(self.conv12(x1))
        y = F.relu(self.conv22(y))
        y = F.relu(self.maxpool(self.conv32(y)))
        #x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        y = y.view(-1,64*8*8)
        y = self.dropout1(y)
        y = F.relu(self.fc12(y))
        y = self.dropout2(y)
        y = self.fc22(y)

        z = F.relu(self.conv13(x1))
        z = F.relu(self.conv23(z))
        z = F.relu(self.maxpool(self.conv33(z)))
        #x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        z = z.view(-1,64*5*5)
        z = self.dropout1(z)
        z = F.relu(self.fc13(z))
        z = self.dropout2(z)
        z = self.fc23(z)

        out = self.fc33(torch.cat((x, y, z), 0))
        
        output = F.log_softmax(out, dim=1)
        return output

import unittest

class TestImplementations(unittest.TestCase):
    
    # Dataloading tests
    def test_dataset(self):
        self.dataset_classes = ['0 - zero',
                                '1 - one',
                                '2 - two',
                                '3 - three',
                                '4 - four',
                                '5 - five',
                                '6 - six',
                                '7 - seven',
                                '8 - eight',
                                '9 - nine']
        self.assertTrue(train_dataset.classes == self.dataset_classes)
        self.assertTrue(train_dataset.train == True)
    
    def test_dataloader(self):        
        self.assertTrue(train_dataloader.batch_size == 32)
        self.assertTrue(test_dataloader.batch_size == 32)      
         
    def test_total_parameters(self):
        model = Net().to(device)
        #self.assertTrue(sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()) == 1015946)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(TestImplementations())
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)

def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # send the image, target to the device
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        # flush out the gradients stored in optimizer
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # pass the image to the model and assign the output to variable named output
        output = model(data)
        # calculate the loss (use nll_loss in pytorch)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
        # do a backward pass
        loss.backward()
        # update the weights
        optimizer.step()
      
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))

def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
          
            # send the image, target to the device
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            # pass the image to the model and assign the output to variable named output
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item() # sum up batch loss
          
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))

model = Net().to(device)

## Define Adam Optimiser with a learning rate of 0.01
optimizer =  torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

start = timeit.default_timer()
for epoch in range(1, 11):
  train(model, device, train_dataloader, optimizer, epoch)
  test(model, device, test_dataloader)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Total time taken: {} seconds'.format(int(stop - start)) )
```

Here is my full code. I couldn't understand what could possibly go wrong...

It is giving

```
<ipython-input-72-194680537dcc> in forward(self, x1)
     46         x = F.relu(self.conv11(x1))
     47         x = F.relu(self.conv21(x))
---> 48         x = F.relu(self.maxpool(self.conv31(x)))
     49         #x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
     50         x = x.view(-1,64*11*11)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Error.

P.S.: Pytorch Noob here.

Comment: Have you tried replacing ```x = F.relu(self.maxpool(self.conv31(x)))``` by ```x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv31(x)))``` in the ```__init__```? If it works, make sure to do it everywhere (i.e. conv32, conv33)

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes, it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly placed a comma at the end of the line where you define `self.maxpool` : `self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2), # Output = 64x11x11` see?
This comma makes `self.maxpool` a tuple instead of a `torch.nn.modules.pooling.MaxPool2d`. Drop the comma at the end and this error is fixed.

Comment: I'm feeling so dumb right now, this solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: No worries. My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't given the stride argument in you definition of `self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)`. Choose one: e.g. `self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride = 2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but still the same error, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LNS_E2p5EB1H4E55eCRta8L12etm8brm?usp=sharing